# Why can't I change Aperture? Canon 60D

Tags: canon, aperture, canon-60d

I am in manual mode (M on the top left scroll wheel above the on button) using a sigma 10-20mm F4-5.6 and then I **spin the scroll wheel** (which has a "set" button in the middle) below the 'q' button, the aperture doesn't change.

It also won't change in Aperture priority mode (AV Mode)

I am a noob with cameras, so I am really stumped

Comment: Have you checked the control wheel isnt "locked" (the button underneath saying "unlock")

Comment: Great, i have made an answer below, it would be great if you could mark it as correct :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like your control wheel is "locked" - press the button underneath it called "unlock" 
This should now let you control the aperture.

Answer (score 3):

Digital Lightcraft gave the correct answer but I'd like to add that you can disable the automatic locking from the menu - the fourth tab from the right, lowest item ("Lock" and a wheel icon).